# Detect if an object is empty

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code:

```
var shown = $('div.slideshow').find('div.slide:visible');
var next = shown.next();

if(next == '') {                        
    console.log('empty');                       
}
```

Basically when the next comes back as empty like: `[]` I want to be able to detect this. How do I do it?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use `length` property, which contains number of elements within jQuery object:

```
if(next.length === 0) {
    console.log('empty');
}
```

or:

```
if(!next.length) {
    console.log('empty');
}
```